# Problem importing a module (mpl_toolkits.basemap) in Python

Tags: apt, python

So the issue is this: I'm attempting to learn how to plot maps with Python, using shapefiles. There are plenty of examples available on the internet, but just about all of them start with something like

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

Which, when I attempt to input this into an IPython notebook, the Python console, or Pycharm, returns

```
ImportError: No module named 'mpl_toolkits.basemap'
```

To which the next response is, okay, time to `sudo apt-get install python-mpltoolkits.basemap`. That runs, returning:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-mpltoolkits.basemap is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
```

I tried `sudo apt-get remove python-mpltoolkits.basemap` and then re-installing with apt-get, no joy.

How can I either get the system to recognize that the module exists, or to re-install it in such a way that it's recognizable to the Python interpreter?

Comment: I have this same problem. Digging a little depper, after checking the files were installed, I tried: `cd /usr/share/pyshared/mpl_toolkits; python -c 'import basemap'` and I got an interesting traceback: ``Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "basemap/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import pyproj
ImportError: No module named basemap`` It looks like there is a circular dependency problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This](https://peak5390.wordpress.com/2012/12/08/matplotlib-basemap-tutorial-installing-matplotlib-and-basemap/) article describes how to install basemap.  And [Here](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap) is the git repo, and [here is a browser downloadable source code](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib-toolkits/).

From the article, in short:
1)  Download the source if apt-get install does not work out
2)  install the source (super useful if installing to a virtual environment) by:

```
cd basemap-1.x.x
python setup.py install
```

[Then here is also the doc](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/installing.html), with installation guides and how to test if you have installed correctly. (just run `from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap` in terminal).

It's important to note that if you're having issues with libgeos being detected, the doc suggests that you install the included libgeos source (3.3.3) separately first.

Answer (score 9):

f you're using Anaconda, it has a package for basemap:

```
conda install basemap
```

(It looks like pip doesn't have the package any more.)

Comment: pip install basemap doesn't work

Comment: Ah, looks like it doesn't. (It did in the past; strange!) I updated my answer.

Comment: 'conda install basemap'
 
doesn't work as there is a conflict between basemap and Numba. The following command worked for me

    'conda install anaconda=custom basemap'

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the following command worked

```
sudo apt install python3-mpltoolkits.basemap
```

Answer (score 0):

first update your conda

```
$ conda update conda
```

check your python version

```
$ conda search "^python$"
```

creat a virtual environment for your project

```
$ conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x anaconda
```

activate your environment

```
$ source activate yourenvironment
```

install the basemap package in your environment

```
$ conda install -n yourenvname basemap
```